# Error when loading object detection model from checkpoint "ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting model to be a trackable object"

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco&list=LL&index=10) using Tensorflow Object detection API for sign language reconition.
when I try to run this cell to load the model from checkpoint:

```
# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)
detection_model

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_PATH, 'ckpt-11')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 detection_model
      6 # Restore checkpoint
----> 7 ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\checkpoint.py:2161, in Checkpoint.__init__(self, root, **kwargs)
   2159 if isinstance(converted_v, weakref.ref):
   2160   converted_v = converted_v()
-> 2161 _assert_trackable(converted_v, k)
   2163 if root:
   2164   # Make sure that root doesn't already have dependencies with these names
   2165   child = trackable_root._lookup_dependency(k)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\checkpoint.py:1521, in _assert_trackable(obj, name)
   1518 def _assert_trackable(obj, name):
   1519   if not isinstance(
   1520       obj, (base.Trackable, def_function.Function)):
-> 1521     raise ValueError(
   1522         f"`Checkpoint` was expecting {name} to be a trackable object (an "
   1523         f"object derived from `Trackable`), got {obj}. If you believe this "
   1524         "object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the "
   1525         "TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.")

ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting model to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got <object_detection.meta_architectures.ssd_meta_arch.SSDMetaArch object at 0x000001D81D3973D0>. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.
```

I do not understand what exactly is causing the error! and how can I solve this?